# Removing an item from a array of objects in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have an array object $a which returns an output like below.

[image: Suppose $a returns this]

And by doing $a[0].Name I can access each "Name" entry,  $a[0].Available I can access its corresponding Available space.

I have another array say $b which contains some names, say $b returns me two names "sandeep_aggr1" and "aggr4". This is just an array (no properties like Name, Avaiable), not an object, so It can't use Compare-Object.

I want to remove other entries in the original object $a, except for those with "Name" equal to "sandeep_aggr1" and "aggr4".

This is what I am doing.

```
foreach($bb in $b)
    {
          foreach($aa in $a)
          {
                if($aa.Name -ne $bb)
                {
                   $aa.Remove($aa.Name)
                }

          }


    }

    echo $a
```

But, I don't see the elements deleted, am I missing something here ?
 Any help appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I'm reading the question correctly, this should work:

```
$a = $a | where {$b -contains $_.Name}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't expect that it's that easy using pipe. Works exactly as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it doesn't work if $a become an array with only one element. Powershell loose the fact that $a is an array. That was very problematic because I used JSON convertion just after.

I just added a cast:

```
$a = [array]($a | where {$b -contains $_.Name})
```